# MediaPlayerLauncher doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am wondering why my MediaPLayerLauncher always throw an error 404 from the server.

I can load all the files I want, ZIP files or jpeg etc with my WebBrowserTask so it means that my url are good and working.
When it comes to mp4 files it doesn't work.

This is the code I am actually using :

```
            if (newPath.Contains(".mp4"))
            {
                MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
                mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(newPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
                mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | MediaPlaybackControls.Stop;
                mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
            }
```

The newPath value will be : http://website.com//files//myfile.mp4

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What type of server is it? Is the server allowed to serve mp4 files?

Comment: It's IIS server. I don't know it works fine on the browser version of the project ..

Comment: Well if it works in your browser, I'm not sure. But in IIS I would check that the mp4 MIME Type is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MediaLocationType.Data is used to specify that the file is stored in the Isolated Storage, try to remove this line.